# In Norse mythology, is there a reference to a stone/rock place, entity, object?

Tags: norse

I've read up a bit but I'm struggling to get a reference to a place, entity or object consisting or containing stone (or rock).

Are there beings, mythological objects, or locations that are characterised by stone in Norse mythology?

Comment: By reference, do you mean, that you are looking for a place or object or being that is made of stone, in Norse mythology?

Comment: Yes a place, object or being made of stone. Or might be a being working with stone or living in a stone house etc.

Comment: It feels *a bit* broad, but I guess if we rule out casual references to common stone objects this could be limited enough in scope. Otherwise - I'm pretty sure [Midgard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midgard) *contains* rocks in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Hrungnir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hrungnir), a mighty [jötunn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6tunn), is said to **have a stone head and heart**, as well as a stone shield and weapon. He appears in the [*Prose Edda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_Edda) where he fought and was slain by [Thor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor). A translation of the account can be found [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/pre/pre05.htm):

> Hrungnir had the heart which is notorious, of hard stone and spiked with three corners, even as the written character is since formed, which men call Hrungnir's Heart. His head also was of stone; his shield too was stone, wide and thick, and he had the shield before him when he stood at Grjótúnagard and waited for Thor. Moreover he had a hone for a weapon, and brandished it over his shoulders, and he was not a pretty sight.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanx @Semaphore!

Comment: So Thor met The Thing and said "Hrungnir! We meet again!" and The Thing says "Whattaya talkin' about, Mary?"